# How to assign output of a for loop to a dataframe/matrix/list

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, matrix, export-to-excel

Data:

**new:**

```
Sl no.   Description
1.       Find your id here
2.       people talk about you
3.       it's your turn

for (i in 1:3) {
    print(cat('count of ',new$Description[i], str_count(new$Description[i], "your")))
}
```

How can I assign this out put to a dataframe and export to excel? Also is it possible to assign to a matrix?

Comment: Do you mean `new$count <- str_count(new$Description,"your")` ?

Comment: Actually i want this descriptions in one coloumn and count against each description in second column and wanna make the output into a dataframe

Comment: Did you try the code in my comment? My code exactly does that.

Comment: yes it's working...thank you so much